# How can I best remove lines with different values grouped on one, but keep the same value even if it appears multiple time grouped on one value

Tags: python, pandas, parsing, text

To help the people trying to help me.  Here is my code.  The errors I get and a sample of real data at the end.

The desired output would eliminate ALL interfaces which have MULTIPLE DIFFERENT MAC VALUES.  Just chucked from the output I want to write to a excel file.  The vlan and type column don't matter.

```
nf_file = filedialog.askopenfilename()  # here we grab a filename to parse
timestr = time.strftime("%m%d")
df = pd.read_csv(nf_file)
#Drop 'interface' with more than one different 'mac'
df['mac_count'] = (df.groupby(['interface'])['mac']).transform('nunique')
df = df.loc[df['mac_count'] == 1]
df = df.drop(['mac_count'], axis=1)
print(df)
```

The errors I get.

Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 16:07:46) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]
wdir='C:/Users/pythonuser/Desktop/companyinfo - Work File/automate1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\pythonuser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3296, in run_code
exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
File "", line 1, in 
runfile('C:/Users/pythonuser/Desktop/companyinfo - Work File/automate1/Python/automate1-v1.py',
wdir='C:/Users/pythonuser/Desktop/companyinfo - Work File/automate1')
File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.3.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.3.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev_pydev_imps_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
File "C:/Users/pythonuser/Desktop/companyinfo - Work File/automate1/Python/automate1-v1.py", line 16, in 
df['mac_count'] = (df.groupby(['interface'])['mac']).transform('nunique')
File "C:\Users\pythonuser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 5810, in groupby
observed=observed,
File "C:\Users\pythonuser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 410, in **init**
mutated=self.mutated,
File "C:\Users\pythonuser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\grouper.py", line 600, in get_grouper
raise KeyError(gpr)

Real CSV I am reading into the dataframe.  There are thousands.

```
vlan     mac       type      interface    
   1    0000.005e.5344    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/1  
   1    0010.5f8f.d6e1    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/2  
   1    0010.5f92.0066    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/2  
   1    0010.5f64.241f    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/2  
   1    0010.5f64.dd4e    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/3  
   1    0010.5f65.1814    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/3  
   1    0012.5f18.4425    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/3  
   1    0012.5f18.61dd    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/2  
   1    0012.5f18.61de    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/3  
   1    0016.2155.18fd    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/5  
   1    0026.5342.5668    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/2  
   1    0026.5343.1048    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/3  
   1    0042.680f.1282    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/1  
   1    0050.600d.5f19    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/3  
   1    0061.e351.14c5    STATIC      Vl1  
   1    00c0.6558.5d5a    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/1  
   1    00c0.65e1.455a    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/1  
   1    00c0.65fe.1e5a    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/1  
   1    00c0.65fe.1e6e    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/1  
   1    3086.6288.1acf    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/5  
   1    3086.6288.1ad0    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/5  
   1    546f.6495.fd93    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/4  
   1    5c5a.c536.689c    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/1  
   1    5c5a.c536.686a    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/2  
   1    5c5a.c536.686e    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/4  
   1    5c5a.c599.3fd4    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/3  
   1    5c5a.c599.40a6    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/1  
   1    5c5a.c599.4066    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/3  
   1    5c5a.c599.40c8    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/3  
   1    5c5a.c599.40cc    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/2  
   1    5c5a.c568.5118    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/1  
   1    5c5a.c568.561e    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/1  
   1    8426.2642.5e6d    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/6  
   1    8ce5.4851.2046    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/1  
   1    6c26.c530.ad32    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/2  
   1    6c26.c530.ad45    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/2  
   1    6c26.c530.6c61    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/3  
   1    6c26.c530.6cc5    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/3  
   1    6c26.c546.a361    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/1  
   1    6c26.c546.a3c5    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/1  
   1    6c26.c563.6331    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/4  
   1    6c26.c563.6345    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/4  
   1    e00e.da82.58f2    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/1  
 501    0000.0c9f.f006    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/1  
 501    0005.36c4.a5f3    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/4  
 501    0016.4f51.1a89    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/2  
 501    0016.4f51.1af4    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/1  
 501    0016.4f51.1614    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/4  
 501    0016.4f51.1615    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/4  
 501    0016.4f51.1625    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/1  
 501    0016.4f51.1635    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/2  
 501    0016.4f51.1639    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/1  
 501    0016.4f51.163c    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/4  
 501    0016.4f51.1641    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/3  
 501    0016.4f51.1645    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/2  
 501    0016.4f51.1665    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/4  
 501    0016.4f51.1666    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/4  
 501    0016.4f51.1650    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/2  
 501    0016.4f51.1651    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/3  
 501    0016.4f51.1654    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/2  
 501    0016.4f51.1656    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/1  
 501    0016.4f51.1655    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/4  
 501    0016.4f51.1656    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/4  
 501    0016.4f51.2ac0    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/1  
 501    0016.4f51.2ac8    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/4  
 501    0016.4f51.2ac9    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/4  
 501    0016.4f51.2acc    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/1  
 501    0016.4f51.2ae9    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/1  
 501    0016.4f51.2aec    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/2  
 501    0016.4f51.2af1    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/2  
 501    0016.4f51.2af6    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/3  
 501    0016.4f51.2afc    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/4  
 501    0016.4f51.2606    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/3  
 501    0016.4f51.2608    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/1  
 501    0016.4f51.2618    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/3  
 501    0016.4f6f.fda8    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/4  
 501    0016.4f6f.fd60    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/4  
 501    0016.4f6f.fd66    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/4  
 501    0016.4f6f.fdd3    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/4  
 501    0016.4f6f.fdd5    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/1  
 501    0016.4f6f.fddc    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/4  
 501    0016.4f6f.fde4    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/4  
 501    0016.4f6f.fe14    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/4  
 501    0016.4f6f.fe15    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/1  
 501    0016.4f6f.fe18    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/1  
 501    0016.4f6f.fe26    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/3  
 501    0016.4f6f.fe43    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/2  
 501    0042.680f.1282    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/1  
 501    0061.e351.14f6    STATIC      Vl501  
 501    5038.eec8.63fc    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/3  
 501    5038.eec8.6401    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/4  
 501    5038.eec8.862e    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/3  
 501    5038.eec8.8ca4    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/3  
 501    5038.eec8.8c61    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/4  
 501    5038.eec8.8c6e    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/3  
 501    5038.eec8.8c6f    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/3  
 501    5038.eec8.8e40    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/2  
 501    5038.eec8.8e4f    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/4  
 501    5038.eec8.8f00    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/2  
 501    5038.eec8.8f03    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/2  
 501    5038.eec8.8f1a    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/2  
 501    5038.eec8.8f1c    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/4  
 501    5038.eec8.8f21    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/2  
 501    5038.eec8.8f25    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/4  
 501    5038.eec8.8f29    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/2  
 501    5038.eec8.8f38    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/2  
 501    5038.eec8.8f39    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/2  
 501    5038.eec8.8f41    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/2  
 501    5038.eec8.8f44    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/3  
 501    5038.eec8.8f46    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/3  
 501    5038.eec8.8f45    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/2  
 501    5038.eec8.8f4f    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/4  
 501    5038.eec8.8f61    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/2  
 501    5038.eec8.8f68    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/1  
 501    5038.eec8.8f54    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/4  
 501    5038.eec8.8f56    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/2  
 501    5038.eec8.8f5e    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/2  
 501    5038.eec8.8f82    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/1  
 501    5038.eec8.8f86    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/2  
 501    5038.eec8.8f8e    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/4  
 501    e00e.da82.58f2    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/1
```

Comment: Just to confirm, the expected output needs only `unique` MAC values? i.e. a `DataFrame` with 5 columns each for 'MYSWITCH`, `1`, `MAC`, `DYNAMIC`, and `Interface` ?

Comment: yes that's pretty much it

Comment: Posted the answer that has two options of removing duplicates using `.drop_duplicates()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Pandas for this. Assuming you load your data into a dataframe as such:

```
    0           1   2               3       4
0   MYSWITCH    1   0000.007e.7344  DYNAMIC Gi1/0/1
1   MYSWITCH    1   00c0.b778.7d5a  DYNAMIC Gi1/0/1
2   MYSWITCH    1   00c0.b7e1.455a  DYNAMIC Gi1/0/1
3   MYSWITCH    1   00c0.b7fe.1e5a  DYNAMIC Gi1/0/1
4   MYSWITCH    1   00c0.b7fe.1e6e  DYNAMIC Gi1/0/1
5   MYSWITCH    1   5c5a.c73b.689c  DYNAMIC Gi1/0/1
6   MYSWITCH    1   5c5a.c799.40a6  DYNAMIC Gi1/0/1
7   MYSWITCH    1   5c5a.c7b8.7118  DYNAMIC Gi1/0/1
8   MYSWITCH    1   5c5a.c7b8.761e  DYNAMIC Gi1/0/1
9   MYSWITCH    1   8ce7.4871.204b  DYNAMIC Gi1/0/1
10  MYSWITCH    1   bc26.c74b.a3b1  DYNAMIC Gi1/0/1
11  MYSWITCH    1   bc26.c74b.a3c7  DYNAMIC Gi1/0/1
12  MYSWITCH    1   001b.2175.18fd  DYNAMIC Gi1/0/5
13  MYSWITCH    1   e00e.da82.78f2  DYNAMIC Gi1/0/11
14  MYSWITCH    3   e00e.da82.78f2  DYNAMIC Gi1/0/11
15  MYSWITCH    1   0042.680f.1282  DYNAMIC Gi1/0/12
16  MYSWITCH    3   0042.680f.1282  DYNAMIC Gi1/0/12
```

You can select only the rows where the interface (column 4) has 1 unique MAC (column 2).

```
import pandas as pd
df.loc[df.groupby(4)[2].transform('nunique')==1]
```

Output

```
    0           1   2               3       4
12  MYSWITCH    1   001b.2175.18fd  DYNAMIC Gi1/0/5
13  MYSWITCH    1   e00e.da82.78f2  DYNAMIC Gi1/0/11
14  MYSWITCH    3   e00e.da82.78f2  DYNAMIC Gi1/0/11
15  MYSWITCH    1   0042.680f.1282  DYNAMIC Gi1/0/12
16  MYSWITCH    3   0042.680f.1282  DYNAMIC Gi1/0/12
```

Comment: Wow Ok I haven't used that command.  But me and Pandas have become best friends because of how much it's helped me at work.  I will try immediately!

Comment: I made sure it's clean but I get about 6 of errors similar to this    line 7632, in groupby
    observed=observed, **kwargs)

Comment: But your output is exactly correct.  I'll keep at it.

Comment: I get specific errors about self-mutating and kwargs not right.  I definitely have it in a dataframe properly I can write it out to excel. Something about the dataframe it doesn't like doing the transform.

Comment: My issue was not using delim=whitespace as I brought the data into Pandas.  It created a dataframe in memory that was right but when I wanted to manipulate it it was trying to treat the dataframe as an object not a columns and rows.  By finally figuring out that stripping the white space, or using regex didn't give me a dataframe that Pandas could use all it functions on and instead using delim-white space it's delivering the results as expected.  I will do some verification but I think this always was, and is the most elegant solve.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit - 3**:

Code below drops all `interface` rows with more than one different `mac`. This is in the Intermediate Output below. Next, optional line drops all duplicate records.

*Note: Some `mac` values in the sample `DataFrame` were changed and may not the same as Edit-1 or the question.*

```
# Import libraries
import pandas as pd

# Create a sample DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'myswitch': ['MYSWITCH']*20,
    'num': [1]*20,
    'mac':[np.nan,'0000.007e.7344','0000.007e.7344',
           '00c0.b7fe.1e5a','00c0.b7fe.1e5a','00c0.b7fe.1e5a',
           '5c5a.c799.40a6','5c5a.c799.40a6','5c5a.c799.40a6',
           '5c5a.c799.40a6','5c5a.c799.40a6','bc26.c74b.a3c7',
           '0042.680f.9999','1111.680f.1282','1111.680f.1282',
           '0042.680f.1282','0042.680f.1282', np.nan,None, ""
          ],
    'dynamic': ['DYNAMIC']*20,
    'interface':['Gi1/0/1']*12 + ['Gi1/0/5'] + ['Gi1/0/11']*2 + ['Gi1/0/12']*2 +
                 ['Gi99/99/99'] + ['Gi88/88/88'] + ['Gi77/77/77']
    
    
})

# Drop 'interface' with more than one different 'mac'
df['mac_count'] = (df.groupby(['interface'])['mac']).transform('nunique')
df = df.loc[df['mac_count']==1]
df = df.drop(['mac_count'], axis=1)
print(df)
```

Intermediate output - 1:

```
    myswitch  num             mac  dynamic   interface
12  MYSWITCH    1  0042.680f.9999  DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/5
13  MYSWITCH    1  1111.680f.1282  DYNAMIC    Gi1/0/11
14  MYSWITCH    1  1111.680f.1282  DYNAMIC    Gi1/0/11
15  MYSWITCH    1  0042.680f.1282  DYNAMIC    Gi1/0/12
16  MYSWITCH    1  0042.680f.1282  DYNAMIC    Gi1/0/12
19  MYSWITCH    1                  DYNAMIC  Gi77/77/77
```

Remove rows with blank `mac`:

```
# Replace and drop blank 'mac'
df['mac'] = df['mac'].fillna(np.nan)
df['mac'] = df['mac'].replace(r'\s+',np.nan,regex=True).replace('',np.nan)
df = df[~df['mac'].isna()]
print(df)
```

Intermediate output - 2:

```
    myswitch  num             mac  dynamic interface
12  MYSWITCH    1  0042.680f.9999  DYNAMIC   Gi1/0/5
13  MYSWITCH    1  1111.680f.1282  DYNAMIC  Gi1/0/11
14  MYSWITCH    1  1111.680f.1282  DYNAMIC  Gi1/0/11
15  MYSWITCH    1  0042.680f.1282  DYNAMIC  Gi1/0/12
16  MYSWITCH    1  0042.680f.1282  DYNAMIC  Gi1/0/12
```

Next, if needed, drop all duplicate rows:

```
# Drop duplicate rows
df = df.drop_duplicates()
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    myswitch  num             mac  dynamic interface
12  MYSWITCH    1  0042.680f.9999  DYNAMIC   Gi1/0/5
13  MYSWITCH    1  1111.680f.1282  DYNAMIC  Gi1/0/11
15  MYSWITCH    1  0042.680f.1282  DYNAMIC  Gi1/0/12
```

---

---

**Edit - 1**

Alternative code using `.drop_duplicates()`:

*Note-1: The sample data below is not exactly same as the question. Added more duplicates.*

Note-2: The duplicates can be removed based on either one or more columns by specifiying the column names in the `subset=` in the code `df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['mac', 'interface'])`. For example:

- if `subset='mac'` then, only unique `mac` in output.
- if `subset=['mac','interface']`, then unique combination of `mac` and
  `interface` in output such that there could be duplicate `mac`
  belonging to different `interface`.

**Option # 1**:

Using data from .txt file

```
### Import libraries
import pandas as pd

### Create DataFrame
# Read data from *.txt file 
path = "<input path here>"
df = pd.read_csv(path+'data.txt', header=None)

# Split and rename columns
df = df['mac'].str.split(' ', expand=True)
df.columns = ['myswitch','num','mac','dynamic','interface']

# Remove duplicates based on column 'mac'
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['mac', 'interface'])

# Output
print(df)
```

**Option # 2**:

Using sample DataFrame

```
# Option-2: Manually create a sample DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'myswitch': ['MYSWITCH']*17,
    'num': [1]*17,
    'mac':['0000.007e.7344','0000.007e.7344','0000.007e.7344',
           '00c0.b7fe.1e5a','00c0.b7fe.1e5a','00c0.b7fe.1e5a',
           '5c5a.c799.40a6','5c5a.c799.40a6','5c5a.c799.40a6',
           '5c5a.c799.40a6','5c5a.c799.40a6','bc26.c74b.a3c7',
           '0042.680f.1282','0042.680f.1282','0042.680f.1282',
           '0042.680f.1282','0042.680f.1282'
          ],
    'dynamic': ['DYNAMIC']*17,
    'interface':['Gi1/0/1']*12 + ['Gi1/0/5'] + ['Gi1/0/11']*2 + ['Gi1/0/12']*2
    
    
})
# Remove duplicates based on column 'mac'
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['mac', 'interface'])
```

Output

```
print(df)

    myswitch  num             mac  dynamic interface
0   MYSWITCH    1  0000.007e.7344  DYNAMIC   Gi1/0/1
3   MYSWITCH    1  00c0.b7fe.1e5a  DYNAMIC   Gi1/0/1
6   MYSWITCH    1  5c5a.c799.40a6  DYNAMIC   Gi1/0/1
11  MYSWITCH    1  bc26.c74b.a3c7  DYNAMIC   Gi1/0/1
12  MYSWITCH    1  0042.680f.1282  DYNAMIC   Gi1/0/5
13  MYSWITCH    1  0042.680f.1282  DYNAMIC  Gi1/0/11
15  MYSWITCH    1  0042.680f.1282  DYNAMIC  Gi1/0/12
```

Comment: And using this way after reading in the file drops duplicate MAC but not the INTERFACE.  The goal is if the interface has multiple different MAC to drop the entire line.

Comment: Trying to understand why there are duplicate `mac` in the expected output posted in the question: `MYSWITCH 1 e00e.da82.78f2 DYNAMIC Gi1/0/11
MYSWITCH 3 e00e.da82.78f2 DYNAMIC Gi1/0/11
MYSWITCH 1 0042.680f.1282 DYNAMIC Gi1/0/12
MYSWITCH 3 0042.680f.1282 DYNAMIC Gi1/0/12
MYSWITCH 1 001b.2175.18fd DYNAMIC Gi1/0/5
MYSWITCH 1 e00e.da82.78f2 DYNAMIC Gi1/0/11
MYSWITCH 3 e00e.da82.78f2 DYNAMIC Gi1/0/11
MYSWITCH 1 0042.680f.1282 DYNAMIC Gi1/0/12
MYSWITCH 3 0042.680f.1282 DYNAMIC Gi1/0/12`                                                          .. Could you post expected output if not above?

Comment: the  rows with Gi1/0/1 wouldn't be there.  Any interface with multiple different MAC the  entire row is dropped.  So in the above output lines with gi1/0/1 would be gone.  And any row with multiple different MAC on the  same  interface would be gone.

Comment: Posted Edit-2 above

Comment: I get output like yours above where the Gi1/0/1 is showing but with no duplicate MAC

Comment: Updated Edit-2. It is difficult for me to diagnose the problem without seeing a dataset that I can use to reproduce the output that you are seeing. I tried to introduce `blanks` and `NaN` in the sample `DataFrame`. Hope it helps.

Comment: I realized the issue with your solve.  The MAC may be different but if there are multiple different MAC on one interface I need to drop the row.  You solve only drops dup mac/interface.  The is not the result I am looking for.

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  My boss out me on something else.  Some answers.  There would be multiple MAC in a switchport acting as trunk.  I am not a Python programmer by job I am a CCNP CIsco engineer.  So that answer may not make sense to you, but it it how switches work.  There will never be NaN lines.  Let me go through your longer answer and try it and see if it is the output I want.  The output I want is what the output from your first answer.  the first answer is exactly what I need I just get errors implementing this line df.loc[df.groupby(4)[2].transform('nunique')==1]

Comment: Your original answer was always the right one.  Thank you. And stuggling along is how i am building my Python skills.  And just for people who Python isn't their core function it's an awesome tangential skill which makes you much  more useful in your IT role.  This little tool will now go log into 2000 switches, collect the interface info like above and parse it out to only interfaces that the client needs.  Rather than a 2 month 3 engineer project of doing it by hand it will take a few day letting this run.  I have paramiko to login and get the info automatically.  My boss loves me.